# Adding function to user form to get User ID

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I'm currently trying to setup a function that will grab and add the user id and input it into the "Owner" field after creating a record in my MS access database. The problem I'm getting currently is it is throwing an error when it gets to the line `me!owner = owner` in the function.

The error I get is this:

[image: Error Message]

The strange thing is this code works under the form I use it in but in the userform it does not. Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
End Sub


Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
Dim c As MSForms.Control
Dim StrSQL As String


For Each c In Me.Controls
If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
If c Then
Select Case c.Name
    Case "CheckBox1"
        'Monday
        Hide
        'Change Notice
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [Need Help]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),2)) mod 7,Date()), 'No')")
        addowner
        'Daily Checks
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [Need Help]) VALUES ('Daily Checks', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),2)) mod 7,Date()),  'No')")
        addowner
    Case "CheckBox2"
        'Tuesday
        Hide
        'Change Notice
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [User ID], [Need Help]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),3)) mod 7,Date()), 'Frontiera', 'No')")
        addowner
        'Daily Checks
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [User ID], [Need Help]) VALUES ('Daily Checks', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),3)) mod 7,Date()), 'Frontiera', 'No')")
        addowner
    Case Else
   End Select
   End If
   End If
  Next c
End Sub

Function addowner()
Dim Owner As String
Owner = Environ("USERNAME")
Me!Owner = Owner '<---Error on this line
End Function
```

Comment: Is there an `Owner` field on the form? `Me!Owner` is shorthand implicit notation for `Me.Controls.Item("Owner")[.Value]`.

Comment: The owner field is from the table it's adding a record to. So I'm probably missing the proper syntax to reference back to the tables (tblTasks) "Owner" field??

Comment: `Me` would be the form itself, not the table. Is the form bound to the table? I'm not very familiar with Access (ok, not at all), but if there's a way to access the form's current record, that would be it - otherwise, you'll want to run an `UPDATE` query, likely with a `WHERE` criteria so as to not change the owner of every single task record in that table. (BTW Access forms are not `UserForm` forms).

Comment: I'm using it like a userform which is why I tagged it as such. The "userforms" are attached to the access database and the check box pop up is initiated by clicking a button from a specific form. If `Me` is based on the form itself I should still be able to use it to grab the user id then right? In the frmTasks I created when you create a new record it grabs your user id from the network and inputs it into the owner field. I'm trying to do the same thing here just when these auto tasks are being generated.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for your help I really appreciate it! I'll have to play around with it as I'm not having much luck currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function normally used to return a value to calling procedure:

```
Function GetOwner()
GetOwner = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function
```

Place that function in a general module and it can be called from anywhere in the database, like:

`Me!Owner = GetOwner()`

If you want this value to populate field of record created with INSERT, concatenate:

`CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [User ID], [Need Help], [Owner]) VALUES ('Daily Checks', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),3)) mod 7, Date()), 'Frontiera', 'No', '" & GetOwner() & "')")`
`

If [Need Help] is a yes/no type field, use `False` (no apostrophes) or 0 instead of `'No'`.

Comment: Thought I added my comment yesterday. But thanks for your help! this worked perfectly! I also took your advice on the yes/no field. Appreciate the help!!!